# Triple Integral Application for Mass Density

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume, density-function

"Find the mass of the region bounded by the xy-plane and the hemisphere $z = \sqrt{100 − x^2 − y^2}$, if the mass density of the region is given by the function $f(x,y,z) = \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$".

So originally I tried graphing this problem but when it comes to determining the bounds for the triple integral is where i fall. I started by attempting to find the individual traces that I can analyze for bounds,

i end up getting: 
[image: progress]

Comment: so basically $f(x,y,z)=\frac{z}{10}$ ?

Comment: im not actually sure.

Comment: After I have showed you how to solve the problem, you can show what you have done.

Comment: @Fakemistake I don't know how to write LaTeX so i edited my question with my progress. i got 1000pi/3. However, this doesn't evaluate in Mathematica

Comment: To @nnmeduthrow I helped with editing your Q...

Comment: @AntonVrdoljak Thank you, do you have resources for learning and writing regex/latex. i am not familiar with it,

Comment: To @nnmeduthrow Check this resource: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* To find the bounds for the hemisphere, note that the flat face is a circle in the $xy$-plane. Now looking at the expression for $z$ and imposing the condition that $z$ be real gives $$100-x^2-y^2\ge 0,$$ which implies $$ x^2+y^2\le 10^2.$$ Thus the radius of the flat face, and hence the hemisphere is $10.$ Solving for $y^2$ in the last inequality gives $y^2\le 10^2-x^2,$ so that $|y|\le \sqrt{10^2-x^2},$ or in other words we have that $$-\sqrt{10^2-x^2}\le y\le \sqrt{10^2-x^2}.$$ Now imposing the condition that $y^2$ be nonnegative gives $0\le 10^2-x^2\implies x^2\le 10^2\implies |x|\le 10,$ or in other words $$-10\le x\le 10.$$ Finally we obtain the bounds for $z$ as varying from $0$ to $\sqrt {100-x^2-y^2}.$

Hence the differential of mass is $$\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dz,$$ so that the desired mass is $$\int_{-10}^{10}\int_{-\sqrt{10^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{10^2-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt {100-x^2-y^2}}\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\frac12\int_{-10}^{10}\int_{-\sqrt{10^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{10^2-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt {100-x^2-y^2}}\frac{2z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\mathrm dz\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-10}^{10}\int_{-\sqrt{10^2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{10^2-x^2}}\int_0^{\sqrt {100-x^2-y^2}}\frac12\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}\mathrm d(x^2+y^2+z^2)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm dx,$$ and the innermost integral is simply $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2},$ which you need to evaluate between the limits $0\le z\le \sqrt {100-x^2-y^2}.$ Then proceed.

Comment: thank you, is it possible to fix the code for the desired mass, i kinda get lost with all the code.

Comment: @nnmeduthrow That's now done.

Comment: thank you. i ended up getting 939, does that sound right?

Comment: That's wrong. You integrate over a square in the $xy$-plane, but it should be a circle.

Comment: @Fakemistake That's true. The range for $y$ should vary with $x.$

Comment: @nnmeduthrow There was a mistake with the bounds for $y.$ Please check edited answer now. Sorry about it.